# Why is the GUI respawned in a loop?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

Following on my small (and first) AutoHotkey GUI I fail to understand why the window is respawned after a `Destroy`:

```
Call:
{
; the "phonebook"
book := {"Tel Maison": "8912", "Tel Mobile": "000000"}
nr := book[A_GuiControl]
; getting rid of the chooser window
Gui, 1:Destroy
; raises the IP phone
; dials the number  
; right now just a debug message 
MsgBox number: %nr%
}   

CapsLock::
Gui, 1:font, cBlue s20 bold, Verdana
Gui, 1:Add, Button, gCall, Tel Maison
Gui, 1:Add, Button, gCall, Tel Mobile
GUI, 1:-Border -SysMenu -Caption
Gui, 1:Show
```

My understanding is that the window is created once, following a `CapsLock` and after the `Show`. When `Call` is called `Gui, 1:Destroy` should close the chooser (the window with the two buttons). Until the next `CapsLock` event.

What actually happens:

- the `Call` routine is called,
- the chooser (GUI window) vanishes
- the `MsgBox` appears
- after clicking `OK` the chooser reappears

Comment: Is this your full script? It is running as expected for me.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the autohotkey.ahk (from memory  - I am not at my desk  but this is the default script). There are a few more lines in it, modifying a few keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you remove the curly brackets and use normal `sub` syntax?  I think you are mixing up `function` and `sub` syntax.

```
Call:
    ;do stuff
Return
```

or use function syntax:

```
Call(){
    ;global    ;uncomment this if you need all the vars global
    ;do stuff
}
```

You should also add `return` after your `capslock` assignment:

```
CapsLock::
    Gui, 1:font, cBlue s20 bold, Verdana
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, gCall, Tel Maison
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, gCall, Tel Mobile
    GUI, 1:-Border -SysMenu -Caption
    Gui, 1:Show
RETURN
```

I think this is your problem.  If you don't close the `call` sub block (the bracket won't close a `sub`) then the GUI gets loaded automatically.

Also, I think another problem is that every time you push capslock, it creates another GUI.  You probably want to remove the old one first and rebuild it OR make it re-usable and just hide and show it.

Rebuilding it is easy:

```
Gui, 1:new   ;this will cause your window to be rebuilt.
gui, 1:font, cBlue s20 bold, Verdana
```

Comment: Thank you - I was not aware of the sub vs function (the docs are not the best one I have seen)

Comment: The best thing you can do is to look at other examples.  Check out DonationCoder - Skrommel has about a hundred and fifty neat little programs all written in autohotkey - you can download both the exe and the source ahk files.  These are great tools to learn and to see what autohotkey can do (and do EASILY)!  http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/